# How to establish communication between Cordova app and Apple watch app?

Tags: swift, cordova, cordova-plugins, apple-watch, hybrid-mobile-app

How can I pass data between my Cordova app and Apple Watch app? Can anyone guide me with any live example? The Github plugin only mentions a very high level of implementation but if there is any live example that will help me a lot. Also, the live demo of GitHub plugin is not working

Comment: Text correction, deleted "thanks"

Comment: Can you please add the link to the Github plugin you are referencing?

Comment: I used d link https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-apple-watch